# Using QStackedLayout to view differant Layouts

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a dialog that has a widget/layout full of pushbuttons.   I can generate a layout that is QHBoxLayout and one that is QGridLayout.  Both work fine.   But now I want to provide the user the option to switch between the two.   So I thought the QStackedLayout with a separate mechanism to setCurrentIndex would be the right answer. Sadly, the code below shows only one set of pushbuttons.  I am missing something, but I can not find out what.  I would hope that I could reuse - and not have two sets - of QCheckBox.  Having 2 sets would cause others programming nightmares.

```
    # Check box's layout ... List
    checksLayoutW0 = QtGui.QWidget()
    checksLayout0 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(checksLayoutW0)
    checksLayout0.setMargin(1)
    checksLayout0.setSpacing(1)      
    self.cbList = []
    for head in self.headers:
        show = not head.hidden and (not head.phase or (head.phase and self.phase))
        if show:
            head_str = str(head)
            checksItem = QtGui.QCheckBox(head_str)
            checksItem.setToolTip("Channel {}".format(head_str))
            checksItem.setObjectName(head_str)
            if head.phase:
                checksItem.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color:Green}")
            self.cbList.append(checksItem)
            checksLayout0.addWidget(checksItem)
    # End Check box layuout - List
    # Check box's layout ... Grid
    checksLayoutW1 = QtGui.QWidget()
    checksLayout1 = QtGui.QGridLayout(checksLayoutW1)
    checksLayout1.setColumnStretch(200,5)
    checksLayout1.setMargin(1)
    checksLayout1.setSpacing(1)      
    column_index = 0
    row_index = 0
    for checkbox in self.cbList:
            checksLayout1.addWidget(checkbox, row_index, column_index)
            if column_index < 4:
                column_index += 1
            else:
                row_index += 1
                column_index = 0
    # End Check box layuout - Grid
    self.checkerHlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.scroll_viewWidget)        
    self.stackedLayout = QtGui.QStackedLayout()
    self.stackedLayout.addWidget(checksLayoutW0)
    self.stackedLayout.addWidget(checksLayoutW1)
    self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(0)
    self.checkerHlayout.addLayout(self.stackedLayout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A widget cannot belong to more than layout. Whenever a widget is added to a layout, it is automatically reparented:

```
>>> w = Qt.QWidget()
>>> vbox = Qt.QVBoxLayout(w)
>>> x = Qt.QWidget()
>>> hbox = Qt.QHBoxLayout(x)
>>> b = Qt.QCheckBox()
>>> vbox.addWidget(b)
>>> b.parent() is w
True
>>> vbox.count()
1
>>> hbox.addWidget(b)
>>> vbox.count()
0
>>> b.parent() is x
True
```

So if you want to change the layout of a set of widgets, you will have to do it dynamically. However, you should be aware that whenever items are removed from a grid-layout, the number of *logical* rows and columns will never decrease, even though the number of *visual* rows or colums may do. Because of this, it may be better to start with a fresh layout each time, rather than trying to re-use an existing one.

Comment: I was worried that behavior was as designed.  So since my CheckBox want to be in both layouts, when I switch I need to 'rebuild' the layout?   Thought I could avoid that.  StackedLayout is more useful when the underlying Widgets are different (say Page 1 is for check deposits and Page 2 is for Online money transfer).  Thanks for the response - will recode my problem to 'build' the layout every time the switch is asked for.